what annotation/configuration change is required to allow this JAX-RS REST endpoint to be "visible"?
(upgrading an existing project to sb324/jdk17)
the project contains a JAX-RS resource that looks like this...
    @Stateless
    @Path("/things")
    [...]
    public class ThingService {

        public ThingService() { 
        }

        @GET
        @Path("{thingName}")
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
        public Thing get(
                @Context jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                @PathParam("thingName") String thingName
                ) 
                
        [...]

after upgrading, when I attempt to call the REST endpoint w/ a "GET" (similar to below)...
curl -k -v -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:8443/thing-service/things/thing01 

...I receive an http status 404  (resource not found)
QUESTION:  what annotation/configuration change would be required to allow this REST endpoint to be "visible"?

Are you just upgrading spring boot, or migrating from standard java-ee environment to it? I'd stay on Java-EE supported environment, like OpenLiberty instead going to SB, otherwise you would have to rewrite your app as springboot dont support EJBs. You would have to replace most of the javaee annotations with springboot proprietary ones. Not worth it, OpenLiberty would be much better choice, as it is modular and supports whole Java/Jakarta EE APIs if needed.
